# Anyway to add some code into the third part library/Assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple third part assembly/library. I would like to add some Console.WriteLine code into it. I do not have its source code. All I can do is using reflector. I am wondering any tool can help achieve this?

Comment: When in the call to a method on this library should `Console.WriteLine` execute? Before? After? Both? Somewhere in the middle?

Comment: YOu can make use of Extension methods here. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to debug the third party assembly, you could see if there is a PDB available for the assembly. I'm not sure how to do it manually, but Resharper will do it for you (you can get a 30 day trial if you just need this temporarily).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly unerstood you can use the [Mono Cecil.](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

to inject code in the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) with the [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) plugin will also let you modify compiled assemblies.